# A way to find source of jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla

I'm working on joomla site, where jquery is loaded in some plugin, module or .. i dont. Is there a way to find out which plugin or module or something is responsible for loading that jQuery script ?

Comment: do a `grep -ir "jquery" .` on the root folder and you'll get a list of matching files.

Comment: Btw I forgot to mention that jquery is loaded from google :/

Comment: in firebug you can see the sequence in which JS files are getting loaded on page. By looking at this load sequence you can roughly judge and can find out which plugin is loading the jQuery

Comment: even if jquery is a cdn/hosted version, the name "jquery" will appear as part of the src of some script tag, hence why i was suggesting to use grep and find exactly what file is including jquery.

Comment: my root folder is / I guess. 

`Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: CWD /grep -ir "jquery" .
Response: 550 Can't change directory to /grep -ir "jquery" .: No such file or directory
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing`

Not sure If I'm doing this right

Comment: do you have a local version of the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is used by a ton of different extensions and very often will be loaded more than once on a particular page. If this is a live site, then your best bet is to install jQuery Easy so you can control what version is being installed or completely suppress jQuery on a particular page.

If it is not a live site or you can work on a backup, the fastest way to figure out what is loading jQuery is to turn off all the plugins, and see if it's gone. It it is, then turn them on one at a time until it comes back. If turning off the plugins doesn't do it, then do the same thing for all of the modules, then for components.

In any case, it is probably preferable to use jQuery Easy to prevent future extensions from causing similar problems.